# ParseError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 50 fields in line 224599, saw 51

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to `pd.concat` multiple .xlsx files in a master CSV and then combine this CSV with past CPU data which is also in CSV format.

The first operation is a success (op 3 out of 8), however on the second pass (history + current data in CSV format - op 7 out of 8) I'm getting the ParseError as shown below.

I've checked both files and there appears to be no separator conflict, data are in the correct columns etc.

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 50 fields in line 224599, saw
>   51

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

def sremove(fn):
    os.remove(fn) if os.path.exists(fn) else None

def mergeit():
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(fl) for fl in path1)
    df.to_csv(path2, index = False)

def mergeit2():
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(fl) for fl in path1)
    df.to_csv(path2, index = False)


print("\n#Operation 3 - Incidents Dataset")
print("Incidents Dataset operation has started")
fn = "S:\\CPU CacheU Data\\201920\\Incidents_201920.csv"
sremove (fn)
print("Incidents 2019/20 file has been deleted - Operation 1 of 8")
path1 = glob.glob('S:\*CPU CacheU Data\*Inc Dataset\Incidents Dataset*.xlsx')
print ("Path 1 - Incidents 2019/20 folder has been read successfully - Operation 2 of 8")
path2 = "S:\\CPU CacheU Data\\Incidents_201920.csv"
print ("Path 2 - Incidents 2019/20 Dataset File has been read successfully - Operation 3 of 8")
mergeit()
print ("Action has been completed successfully - Incidents Dataset 2019/20 Updated - Operation 4 of 8")
fn = "S:\\CPU CacheU Data\\Incidents_Dataset.csv"
sremove(fn)
print (" Incidents Dataset Old file has been deleted - Operation 5 of 8")
path1 = glob.glob('S:\*CPU CacheU Data\*Incidents_*.csv')
print ("Path 1 - Incidents folder has been read successfully - Operation 6 of 8")
path2 = "S:\\CPU CacheU Data\\Incidents_Dataset.csv"
print ("Path 2 - Incidents Dataset File has been read successfully - Operation 7 of 8")
mergeit2()
print ("Path 2 - Incidents Dataset File has been updated successfully - Operation 8 of 8")
```

A couple of notes:

1) Op 3 out of 8 takes a really long time to run. I'm not sure if that's because of the xlsx to csv conversion.

2) I've tried to add the `error_bad_lines = False` statement in the `def mergeit2()` function but it seems to be taking forever to generate the master file.

Comment: check separators in your csv file, maybe there are more commas inside cells , read_csv is taking by default `sep=','`

Comment: @sygneto You are amazing! It was the `sep = ' ' ` statement eventually. Although the columns were split by space, I needed to specify it in my `pd.read_csv()` function

Comment: great, so i will add it as official answer

Comment: Yes please, that'd be perfect. I'll upvote it and mark it as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check separators in your csv file, maybe there are more commas inside cells , read_csv is taking by default `sep=','`
Propably you should set different separator to open your csv file
`pd.read_csv(sep=' ')`